# Looping through objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, javascript-objects

I know this is something I should be knowing, but I'm having trouble figuring it out.

```
const food = {
  "design": [
    {
      "forTemperature": {
        "high": "100",
        "low": "70"
      },
      "productURL": "",
      "imageURL": ""
    },
    {
      "forTemperature": {
        "high": "80",
        "low": "65"
      },
      "productURL": "",
      "imageURL": ""
    },
    {
      "forTemperature": {
        "high": "75",
        "low": "65"
      },
      "productURL": "",
      "imageURL": ""
    },
    {
      "forTemperature": {
        "high": "67",
        "low": "60"
      },
      "productURL": "",
      "imageURL": ""
    }
  ]
}
```

Basic json file i have, objects inside an array, but doing something like:

```
food.design.map((item, i) => i
```

doesn't work for me.

What approach do I need to go about?

---

```
import food from "./apiDesign.json";


const New = props => {

  const [food, setFood] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {

    const fetchAPI = async e => {
      const designer = await food;
      setFood(designer);
    };

    fetchAPI();

  }, [])

  const stuff = () => {
    return loop // I was trying to loop it in here
  };

  return (
    {stuff}
  )
}

export default New;
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: food.design.map((item, i) => i); // returns [0,1,2,3]. Can you explain which values you need. Also do you want to map() or loop?

Comment: @assoron @AswinKumar I'm getting `Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`

Comment: @hellomello In what enviroment are you running the code? Because I am quite sure that on the usual online REPL's this is running fine.

Comment: @assoron I'm running it in codesandbox.io with reactjs. is that what you're asking? sorry! also, thanks for your help!

Comment: @hellomello since you are using reactjs this sounds to be a async problem very likely? Are you using the hardcoded example to run your code or is there somewhere a promise or the like where you wait on the data?

Comment: @assoron so i created a json file and i just inserted it into my component and I did do a async/await on it. is that the issue?

Comment: @assoron I updated my question to see what it looks like so far

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me, as you can see its looping through the array properly. What is your issue?

```js
const food = {
  "design": [
    {
      "forTemperature": {
        "high": "100",
        "low": "70"
      },
      "productURL": "",
      "imageURL": ""
    },
    {
      "forTemperature": {
        "high": "80",
        "low": "65"
      },
      "productURL": "",
      "imageURL": ""
    },
    {
      "forTemperature": {
        "high": "75",
        "low": "65"
      },
      "productURL": "",
      "imageURL": ""
    },
    {
      "forTemperature": {
        "high": "67",
        "low": "60"
      },
      "productURL": "",
      "imageURL": ""
    }
  ]
}

food.design.map((item, i) => console.log(i, item))
```

Comment: @hellomello - where do you get it? When you hit the button `Run code snippet`?

Comment: Oh I c what you're saying. Hmm, the issue is happening on my testing side. Is this supposed to work if I'm dealing with reactjs? Or it should be the same?

Comment: @hellomello - yes it should work, you are obviously doing something else wrong. The error tells you that in object you are using the `design` subobject does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

The method below will return each object that is inside of *food.design*:

```
food.design.map(item => { /* do something here */ });
```

Comment: It will return an array of transformed copies of each object inside food.design.

Comment: @assoron that is true, but he didn't mention what his desired output is so according to the information we currently have I think this is acceptable for now.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ECMA Script 6 then use this one

```
const food = {
  "design": [
    {
      "forTemperature": {
        "high": "100",
        "low": "70"
      },
      "productURL": "",
      "imageURL": ""
    },
    {
      "forTemperature": {
        "high": "80",
        "low": "65"
      },
      "productURL": "",
      "imageURL": ""
    },
    {
      "forTemperature": {
        "high": "75",
        "low": "65"
      },
      "productURL": "",
      "imageURL": ""
    },
    {
      "forTemperature": {
        "high": "67",
        "low": "60"
      },
      "productURL": "",
      "imageURL": ""
    }
  ]
}
const obj =  food.design;
for (const key of Object.keys(obj)) {
    console.log(key, obj[key]);
}
```